# iOS Xamarin scheduled timer not firing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

We have a scheduler logic in an Xamarin (not *Forms*) project, which existed for quite some time and once worked. With one of the iOS upgrades (could be quite some time ago), the scheduler stopped firing events.

Why is the timer below not firing every 20 seconds? The app is active, the screen is on and I validated that the initialization code runs exactly once.

```
var interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
Timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(interval, HandleScheduledEventMethod);

// ...

public void HandleScheduledEventMethod(NSTimer timer)
{
    // never executed, except for each call to Timer.Fire()
}
```

I added it to the NSRunLoop as advised in the Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer), but that did not help either.

```
NSRunLoop.Main.AddTimer(Timer, NSRunLoopMode.Common);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddTimer` must be called on the main thread, it does not work when called on a background thread.

```
DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchQueue(() => {
  Timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(interval, HandleScheduledEventMethod);
  NSRunLoop.Main.AddTimer(Timer, NSRunLoopMode.Common);
})
```